# Navigate to different pages on the basis of group name in flutter

Tags: flutter, materialpageroute

I have created one application in which all the group names are fetched. Now, I want the functionality in which if I click on group name "Technical", I will be redirected to UI Page of Technical group. When I click on group name "Medical", I will be redirected to UI Page of Medical group and in similar manner. UI of all the pages are different. I have used firebase as backend. I am new to flutter and will be very much grateful to you if you can help me.

Source code of group_chat_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:chat_app/group_chats/create_group/add_members.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/group_chats/group_chat_room.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GroupChatHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GroupChatHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GroupChatHomeScreenState createState() => _GroupChatHomeScreenState();
}

class _GroupChatHomeScreenState extends State<GroupChatHomeScreen> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isLoading = true;

  List groupList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAvailableGroups();
  }

  void getAvailableGroups() async {
    String uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;

    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('groups')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        groupList = value.docs;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Groups"),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              height: size.height,
              width: size.width,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: groupList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => GroupChatRoom(
                        groupName: groupList[index]['name'],
                        groupChatId: groupList[index]['id'],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.group),
                  title: Text(groupList[index]['name']),
                );
              },
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.create),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => AddMembersInGroup(),
          ),
        ),
        tooltip: "Create Group",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Source code of group_chat_room.dart:

```
import 'package:chat_app/group_chats/group_info.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GroupChatRoom extends StatelessWidget {
  final String groupChatId, groupName;

  GroupChatRoom({required this.groupName, required this.groupChatId, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController _message = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(groupName),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => GroupInfo(
                        groupName: groupName,
                        groupId: groupChatId,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it' very easy just check your group name in onTap and according to your group name use if else condition and navigate to that screen:

```
          ListView.builder(
          itemCount: groupList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              onTap: () {
        if(groupList[index]['name']=="Technical"){
   
        Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => TechnicalChatRoom(
                    groupName: groupList[index]['name'],
                    groupChatId: groupList[index]['id'],
                  ),
                ),
                   }
       
         if(groupList[index]['name']=="Arts"){

       MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ArtsChatRoom(
                    groupName: groupList[index]['name'],
                    groupChatId: groupList[index]['id'],
                  ),
                ),
          and so on
           .......
                  ...

             }

              ),}
               ,
              leading: Icon(Icons.group),
              title: Text(groupList[index]['name']),
            );
          },
        ),
```